# Making a change from Chemistry to Computer Science

Tags: graduate-school, computer-science, undergraduate, changing-fields

I am set to graduate with a bachelors degree in Chemistry in the fall, however, I feel as if I am making a mistake.  I feel that my true passion lies in computer science.

I love research, everything from the frustration to the feeling of making progress, and I would love to do something involving academia in the future.

I learned python and data science from online courses and really became interested in it when I took some probability and statistics classes and my professors showed us what they were doing.  I feel like that would be something I would enjoy doing, data, machine learning, bioinformatics, etc.

My question is, I'm not sure how to proceed.  Should I graduate and return to school for a second bachelor in CS?  Should I change my major and stay an extra year or two?  Self-learn?

Thank you and I'm sorry if this is the wrong board to post.  I really don't know where else to turn!

Thank you

Comment: In which country do you study ? We can't say what you want to do, just giving advices. From what I know, continuing in a subject you don't like is a bad idea. But at the same time, since I don't know where you are from, I can't say if you would be able to pretend an equivalence of your diploma, something like that.

Comment: @Gautier I'm sorry.  I am from the US.  BA in Chemistry.

Comment: edit your message then :) I don't know exactly how the US system is working BUT from my own experience, what you have to do is to check what you are able to get as equivalency with your bachelor in Chemistry. Then, when you list all your options, you might be able to choose something.

Comment: @mr-smith you might want to check [that](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6720/overlap-between-computer-science-and-chemistry)

Comment: Combine the two ... there are topics in computational chemistry. I'm not an expert but I'm sure I've seen that modelling reaction kinetics is highly computer intensive.